# Replaced String in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

So I'm trying to build my app for iOS 9 and am running into one problem. Before, I had a button that would take the string from a label and add it to a string that would take a person to lmgtfy and automatically search for the contents of the string, but now I'm running into an error with map(). Here is the code that worked in iOS 8:

```
        @IBAction func googleButton() {
        let replaced = String(map(originalString.generate()) { $0 == " " ? "+" : $0 })
        if let url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com/?q=\(replaced)") {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        }

            print(replaced)
        }
```

So now the error I'm getting says, "'map' is unavailable: call the 'map()' method on the sequence." Any ideas? Also, I'm not positive that link will work because it is supposed to be lmgtfy but I couldn't submit this question unless I changed the URL to google.

Comment: `originalString.generate().map()` instead of `map(originalString.generate())` if I'm reading the error correctly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of Swift 2, `String` no longer conforms to [`SequenceType`](http://swiftdoc.org/swift-2/protocol/SequenceType/), therefore you can't call `generate`  on it. Instead you need to use the `characters` property to obtain a [`String.CharacterView`](http://swiftdoc.org/swift-2/type/String.CharacterView/), which does conform to `SequenceType`.

Also with Swift 2: `map` is a method in an extension of `SequenceType`. Therefore you call it like a method, instead of a free function:

```
let str = "ab cd ef gh"
let replaced = String(str.characters.map { $0 == " " ? "+" : $0 }) 
// "ab+cd+ef+gh"
```

You could also do:

```
let replaced = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+")
// "ab+cd+ef+gh"
```

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar. Looks like that fixed my problem! Thank you!